# How to use the Python (with numpy?) to do the recursive calculation for a self-referencing expression?

Tags: python-3.x

Since after re-writting my question there is still no further answer, I try to describe my question in another way.

The expression looks as follow:

```
y = a*(datas + Prev(datas,1)/2) + b*Prev(y,1) + c*Prev(y,2)
```

The a, b and c are constants.

The datas is a Series and has n-elements.

The Prev(datas,1) is the privious value of datas.

The initial values of y are 0 and can be defined as:

```
y = pd.Series(np.zeros_like(datas))
```

The Prev(y, 1) is the privious of y and the Prev(y,2) is the privious of Prev(y,1)

Comment: you can just return the value without declaring the filt variable using __return( c1*(price + price.shift(1))/2 + c2*filt.shift(1) + c3*filt.shift(2))__

Comment: Sorry, I've tried again, simply using return( c1*(price + price.shift(1))/2 + c2*filt.shift(1) + c3*filt.shift(2)) doesn't work. I got error: global name 'filt' is not defined

Comment: I do not really get what you are trying to do here since you are using `filt` as a variable. Can you insert your code where you use it as a function

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change a global variable in python you need to reference it again in your function

```
def computeSuperSmootherFilter(price, cutoffLength):
    global filt # Needed to modify global copy of globvar
    a1 = np.exp(-math.pi * math.sqrt(2)/cutoffLength )
    b1 = 2 * a1 * math.cos( math.sqrt(2) * math.pi / cutoffLength )
    c2 = b1
    c3 = -a1*a1
    c1 = 1- c2 - c3
    filt = c1*(price + price.shift(1))/2 + c2*filt.shift(1) + c3*filt.shift(2)

    return filt
```

Comment: A word of caution - [Why are global variables evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)

Comment: Hi Jan, as I wrote in my post, defining the 'filt' as a global doesn't return the correct values since here the 'filt' is not a variable, but a function.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the solution to my question myself. I do as follow:

```
y=pd.Series(np.zeros_like(datas))

for i in range(len(datas)):    
    try:
        y[i] = c1*(datas[i] + datas[i-1])/2 + c2*y[i-1] + c3*y[i-2]
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    y
```